# ggplot: Issue when converting axis values from number of days to months in a boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, as.date

When converting a numeric variable "number of days from 1st of January of 2015" to date, the boxplot only shows part of the range of y-values but not all.

In this example, I plotted "gender" vs "months". Months were obtained by transforming the original "days" variable (i.e. days starting from 2015/1/1). The range of numeric values should extend from the end of March to the beginning of April of the subsequent year, but ggplot() is only plotting values between Aug and Jan and showing only month labels within that range in the y-axis.

Any help to solve this issue is very welcome!

Here is the code and the corresponding plot:

```
    gender <- c(rep("female",144), rep("male",144))  
days <- c(274,285,302,330,117,230,271,207,235,249,268,NA,NA,NA,NA,210,255,290,267,252,257,268,288,220,264,270,277,303,222,252,296,323,369,NA,258,NA,240,245,310,271,272,282,314,345,214,211,258,268,145,176,244,273,249,257,277,284,272,273,272,282,290,297,260,266,277,213,247,244,269,349,268,NA,220,235,269,299,266,273,274,307,285,299,300,224,257,284,291,305,278,294,455,280,262,272,276,295,338,264,339,232,277,230,270,312,276,285,308,241,273,340,249,260,270,352,297,217,247,287,320,191,249,265,287,320,432,262,265,324,309,234,441,409,264,381,262,276,316,330,252,264,298,315,287,330,274,287,371,237,259,266,349,247,249,241,333,379,486,198,249,270,275,279,314,182,234,252,289,319,216,262,293,234,272,284,311,258,NA,299,314,290,292,296,300,274,289,359,267,319,NA,492,294,319,293,265,273,315,307,315,287,378,238,239,315,325,361,249,NA,192,224,226,204,208,234,263,283,294,430,267,273,307,327,460,240,307,319,492,300,311,485,348,297,348,317,317,318,338,316,316,336,255,284,316,249,302,307,308,301,265,273,316,281,326,272,283,NA,NA,243,254,271,191,259,324,287,265,310,337,287,326,304,399,337,295,313,228,288,307,270,347,290,245,NA,283,423,223,NA,264,314,283)
mytable <- data.frame(gender,days)
range(mytable$days, na.rm=T) # 117 to 492
mytable$months <- (as.Date(days,origin = "2015/1/1"))

ggplot(mytable, aes(x=gender, y=months,fill=gender)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the intuition behind this plot. But, this would give you what you desire:

```
ggplot(mytable, aes(x=gender, y=months, fill=gender)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_y_date(date_labels="%b ", date_breaks  ="1 month", 
               limits = c(as.Date("2015-3-1"), as.Date("2016-2-1")))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! that's exactly what I need. Make not much sense, but only after the description.